# jQuery validator plugin - double meta

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation, meta

I am running jQuery validator plugin... and my validation looks:

> .validate({ errorElement: "em", errorContainer: $("#summary"),
>   errorLabelContainer: $("ol", $("#summary")), wrapper: 'li', meta:
>   "validate"...

I have a situation where I have two different SELECT fields for an address and for a shipping address... on the same form...

Example validation messages:

```
messages: {
Surname: 'Enter your Surname',
ShippingSurname: 'Enter your Shipping Surname'
}
```

> My question: How to achieve the situation where I will keep two
>   different validations even If I will change the country on the select
>   list? Is it possible without having two different forms/ids?

I want:
one form, two different addresses, two different error messages/validations...